# Font size on mobile device is large

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the font size on my webform so that it looks smaller if displayed on a mobile device (currently using android).  By changing the css file to render the text to say font-size:small when viewed from the browser it works fine but when viewing the same page on the phone the text doesnt seem to get smaller so everything (including the controls) look huge
Im using bootstrap but not sure on how to use responsive font sizes, however I would expect the above to work, here is the header

```
<head runat="server">

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle?

Comment: I've since tried the .small and/or the .h6 bootstrap css and the text has now gone smaller still my gridview table doesnt fit onto the mobile phone page so will try looking at responsive font css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">` in your header and you can use media queries for mobile devices as per Chris Coyer's [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    .targetClass {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I think this seems to be working - whats the difference between this method and the bootstrap way?  is there are difference? Is there a way to achieve the above using bootstrap?

Comment: @AShah Bootstrap is a framework that takes care of _most_ cases. There are exceptions for which it's best to add tweaks to a separate css file and it's still the Bootstrap way. You're extending Bootstrap, something every website will have to do sooner or later or they'd all look the same :) If this helped, I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer as correct or if there is more help you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link in your head tag

```
<head>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all"    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</head>
```

If the link doesn't work for you ,Then you need to write media queries for you required screen size with the fonts you need to display.

Comment: This only links to available Google fonts. It doesn't change any font sizes by adding this to the head.

Comment: @mijopabe then you need to write  media queries for you required screen size with the fonts you need to display.

Comment: I agree but it could to be reflected in your answer as I'm assuming the author doesn't know if he/she is having difficulties with this. :)